# Partition by / over OR CROSS APPLY.. confused

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having an interesting requirement, hope someone would guide through to achieve the result! TIA.

**Table:**

```
Student   Date & Time      ClassAttended  Session
Joel      07/20 10:00AM    YES            Single
Joel      07/21 10:00AM    NO             Single
Joel      07/22 10:00AM    YES            Multiple
Joel      07/20 11:00AM    NO             Multiple
Joel      07/20 02:00PM    YES            Multiple
Joel      07/20 03:00PM    NO             Multiple
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Student   Date & Time      ClassAttended  Session
Joel      07/21 10:00AM    NO             Single
Joel      07/22 11:00AM    NO             Multiple
Joel      07/22 03:00PM    NO             Multiple
```

My goal is to come up with the above result, with or without the `Session` column's presence!

Comment: Seems like a dead-simple SELECT with WHERE clause. Why is this worthy of a question here?

Comment: Thanks Pieter. What is present above is a sample, actual table has different students and values. **Why is this worthy of a question here?** – how to get result via SQL where last unsuccessful attendant to be listed, and in case when there are multiple sessions in the mix.

Comment: I don't really understand the goal here. What exactly is "with or without the `Session` column's presence" meant to indicate? The column is *always* present.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I have tried to get result without Session column, where logic became tough so I end-up adding the column to make Partition easier (I guess). I would like to get result with or without this extra column.. hope I have clarified.

Comment: Could you add in some pseudo-code to indicate what you want to be returning? I know you gave the example, but I'm having a problem trying to visualize the discerning factors of these. I'm sure it's just me, but some pseudo-code would really help.

Comment: As for your desired result goes it is simple where clause with classattended as 'No'.If your requirement is last unsuccessfull attendance (across student).then your desired result is wrong.

Comment: Give us the query you are using and/or the query (right or wrong) that you think should work. If you aren't sure what you are asking we aren't sure how to answer.